# OpenGL: How to get a pointer into video RAM for a texture's pixels?

Tags: opengl, video, ram

I would like to directly access the pixels of texture in video ram. Is this possible in OpenGL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The whole idea of OpenGL is to provide an **abstraction** of GPU hardware that applies across vendors and architectures. Allowing direct access to VRAM would break this abstraction in a lot of ways:

- It assumes that the system has VRAM.
- It assumes that the texture is currently in VRAM. Even on systems that have VRAM, the texture could not be in VRAM at any given time, or never at all.
- It would potentially restrict the memory format/layout of the data in VRAM, because it would become accessible from outside. The layout of the pixels in VRAM can be very different from the layout in system memory.

Even putting aside all of this for a moment, you might not be very happy with the result if you actually had an option to do this. Accessing VRAM from the CPU is not necessarily very efficient.